# AngularJS function not aware of new dom element after $compile

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dom

I have a directive which at the end of everything else it does, appends a new dom element that was created in memory to the body using the `$compile` method in this way

```
app.directive('transitionBackground', function ($compile) {
   return {
       restrict: 'E',
       link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

           ...lots of code...
            function compile () {
                $compile(_stageElement)(scope).appendTo("body");
                animate();                
            }
    function animate() {
        console.log($(".newElement"));
    }

}
```

When the log function happens, the new element selector returns an empty array, however when I use the console in my browser to log the same selector I get the new element as expected.  When I take the compile piece off I cannot even do that, so I know the compile method is working.  Why can't the animate function see it?

Comment: Looks like $compile might be asynchronous. Can you put `animate()` in a $timeout callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element is probably not rendered yet, which is why you can access it from the debug console (long, long after the `animate` function runs).

Have a look at the answer of this question: [AngularJS: How can I run a directive after the dom has finished rendering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240639/angularjs-how-can-i-run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering), I'm guessing that will solve your issue.

Comment: Ha!  Worked like a charm.  That's strange to me, I was of the impression that the browser was always synchronous.  Go figure.