# Working with a custom canvas directive in angularJS does not show anything

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, canvas

I am building a custom AngularJS 1 directive, based on a canvas. But I can't see the rectangle I am drawing on the canvas :

```
angular.module('loloof64.chess_diagram', [])
  .directive('chessDiagram', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "E",
      template: '<canvas width="{{size}}" height="{{size}}"></canvas>',
      scope: {
        size: '@'
      },
      compile: function(element, attrs) {

        drawBackground = function(scope, canvasCtx) {
          canvasCtx.fillStyle = "#DD55CC";
          canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, scope.size, scope.size);
        };


        return function(scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.size = scope.size - scope.size % 9;
          scope.cellSize = Math.floor(scope.size / 9);
          canvas = element[0].children[0];
          ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          drawBackground(scope, ctx);
        };

      }
    };
  });
```

Here is [my plunker live preview](https://plnkr.co/edit/j0FKaOS0xMG51blisQ1u?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue here is that you are calling `fillRect` before dom has finished rendering. There is already a thread on [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240639/how-can-i-run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering) for that.

Wrap you call to `drawBackground` within `$timeout` with zero delay.

```
$timeout(function() {
    drawBackground(scope, ctx);
});
```

And also don't forget to inject $timeout in your directive:

```
.directive('chessDiagram', function($timeout) {
```

Further `scope.size` is `NaN`. Give it a value may be in html like this

```
<chess-diagram size="100"></chess-diagram>
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot this important point. Also forgot to provide size value. (Coming from java)