# Is $timeout still best practice for waiting on Angular directive template?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, directive

Our team's design pattern for waiting on a directive's template to render is to wrap our DOM manipulation code in a `$timeout` (inside the directive's link function), which I know at one time was the normal design pattern. Is that still true, or are there better/safer design patterns to do this?

Example of pattern is in ECMAScript6:

```
link: ($scope, $element) => {
  $timeout(() => {
     var domElementFromTemplate = $element.find('myDOMElement');
  } 
}
```

Comment: It's been a long time to be honest... We've been using AngularJS for about 2 years, so it would have been something I read back then.

Comment: Please give me a link.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240639/how-can-i-run-a-directive-after-the-dom-has-finished-rendering

There's one.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11125078/is-there-a-post-render-callback-for-angular-js-directive

And another.

Comment: It's not a best practice but it's a valid option to wait for some bindings to be executed. For example, when using a ng-if. This way, you can execute code once the HTML has been injected in your page. $timeout just add a function in the event loop task queue.

Comment: I'm going to give a few of the suggestions a try on Monday.   I was unaware a document ready would fire more than once on a single page app, so that solution makes me curious.  ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### While you try to select an element which is available in DOM:

It never been a best practise IMO because there is no need to create an asynchronous behavior to an synchronous dom select function. Due to the [angular.element documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) it should look like this:

```
link: ($scope, $element) => {
    var domElementFromTemplate = $element.find('myDOMElement');
}
```

---

#### While you try to select an element which is supposed to be rendered in your directive:

The timeout function should avoid DOM-rendering async behavior but IMO there are a lot more better approaches to deal with this issue:

---

#### Solution 1)

An other approach is to get the document ready state to ensure you element is available in DOM like:

```
link: ($scope, $element) => {
    angular.element(document).ready(() => {
        var domElementFromTemplate = $element.find('myDOMElement');
    });
}
```

---

#### Solution 2)

An other approach is to create an other directive for those elements, which were rendered inside a directive, e.g. (`myDOMElement`) to avoid DOM injection at all.

```
link: ($scope, $element) => {},
template: "<div some-other-child-directive></div>"
```

---

#### Solution  3)

It should be a much better and more neat approach to create a callback function to ensure the element is available in DOM. This could be done by `ng-init="someCallback()"` to start up your element functionalities.

---

#### Solution  4)

Yes, using `$timeout` still works fine while a new `$timeout` will be added to the to the execution queue and will be executed after the DOM was rendered. A timeout delay value is not needed.

```
link: ($scope, $element) => {
    $timeout(() => {
        var domElementFromTemplate = $element.find('myDOMElement');
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that doesn't work.   If the DOM element is in your directive's template.  It may work sometimes on fast machines when hosted locally.